# Update EER Diagram from live server (with sql command) in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rdbms

I already know how to synchronize model, forward enginner changes and reverse engineer an existing db. Now I have a problem.
I have a database `db_a` and I created a model by reverse engineering it. I edited this model many times with **Synchronize Model**. So this sql script automatically created with this commands in my live server.

> Sometimes, I need a completely reversed process of the above. I want to write
>   some sql script in my live server directly and then I want to update
>   my model to same EER diagram.

I tried **Synchronize Any Source** to take updates from my live database server. But this process doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear which sql script you mean. There is no such script on a MySQL server. A script is the SQL code for database objects, their data and commands for other tasks.

Comment: Suppose I want rename a table. So I execute a sql command on my live server like RENAME TABLE  `dealerportal`.`leadboard_activities` TO  `dealerportal`.`leadboard_notes` ; . and then I want update my model at the same time. (table name leadboard_notes instead of leadboard_activities in my EER DIAGRAM ) @MikeLischke

Answer (score 0):

The synchronize feature is supposed to bring both sides up-to-date. It should pick up any changes made on the server side and vice versa. However, since there is no version control info available in that process it is difficult to track renames. One rename should be ok, but several cannot be detected anymore. All the diff code used to do the synchronization is based on object names, because of the lack of other information.

So, try with a simple change first (say, the data type of a column) and see if the sync process picks this up. Also take a closer look at the sync window.

[image]

The green arrows can be clicked to change the direction of the sync or to disable a particular change. In the image you can also see actions resulting from renames (in the model).